# How To Implement Tie function into Tic-Tac-Toe With Nested Lists

Tags: nested-loops

In my game, I am trying to add a tie function by using else under my win determiner, but I'm having trouble. Can someone help me add a tie function into my code under the win determiner? I have tried to add else under the win determiner, but the tie will end up printing that the game has ended in a tie randomly. Some help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
player1 = str(input("What is player X's name?"))
print()
player2 = str(input("What is player O's name?"))
turn = 1
location = [
  [' ',' ',' '],
  [' ',' ',' '],
  [' ',' ',' '],
]
while turn <= 9:
  if turn % 2  == 1:
    print()
    print("It is currently " +player1+ "'s turn")
    row = int(input("What row would you like to mark?"))-1
    print()
    col = int(input(" What column would you like to mark?"))-1
    print()
    while "O" in location[row][col]:
      print(player1+" that spot has already been taken")
      print("Please pick again")
      row = int(input("What row would you like to mark?"))-1
      print()
      col = int(input(" What column would you like to mark?"))-1
      print()
    location[row][col] = "X"
    print(location[0][0] + '|' + location[0][1] + '|' + location[0][2])
    print("-----")
    print(location[1][0] + '|' + location[1][1] + '|' + location[1][2])
    print("-----")
    print(location[2][0] + '|' + location[2][1] + '|' + location[2][2])
    turn = turn + 1
    if ((location[0][0] == 'X' and location[0][1] == 'X' and location[0][2] 
    == 'X') or 
      (location[1][0] == 'X' and location[1][1] == 'X' and location[1][2] == 
    'X') or 
      (location[2][0] == 'X' and location[2][1] == 'X' and location[2][2] == 
    'X') or
      (location[0][0] == 'X' and location[1][0] == 'X' and location[2][0] == 
    'X') or 
      (location[0][1] == 'X' and location[1][1] == 'X' and location[2][1] == 
    'X') or
      (location[0][2] == 'X' and location[1][2] == 'X' and location[2][2] == 
    'X') or
      (location[0][0] == 'X' and location[1][1] == 'X' and location[2][2] == 
    'X') or 
      (location[0][2] == 'X' and location[1][1] == 'X' and location[2][0] == 
    'X')):
      print (player1+" won the game!")
      turn = 10
    else:
      print("The game ended in a tie!")
  else:
    print("It is currently " +player2+ "'s turn")
    row = int(input("What row would you like to mark?"))-1
    print()
    col = int(input(" What column would you like to mark?"))-1
    print()
    while "X" in location[row][col]:
      print(player2+" that spot has already been taken")
      print("Please pick again")
      row = int(input("What row would you like to mark?"))-1
      print()
      col = int(input(" What column would you like to mark?"))-1
      print()
    location[row][col] = "O"
    print(location[0][0] + '|' + location[0][1] + '|' + location[0][2])
    print("-----")
    print(location[1][0] + '|' + location[1][1] + '|' + location[1][2])
    print("-----")
    print(location[2][0] + '|' + location[2][1] + '|' + location[2][2])
    turn = turn + 1
    if ((location[0][0] == 'O' and location[0][1] == 'O' and location[0][2] 
    == 'O') or 
      (location[1][0] == 'O' and location[1][1] == 'O' and location[1][2] == 
    'O') or 
      (location[2][0] == 'O' and location[2][1] == 'O' and location[2][2] == 
    'O') or
      (location[0][0] == 'O' and location[1][0] == 'O' and location[2][0] == 
    'O') or 
      (location[0][1] == 'O' and location[1][1] == 'O' and location[2][1] == 
    'O') or
      (location[0][2] == 'O' and location[1][2] == 'O' and location[2][2] == 
    'O') or
      (location[0][0] == 'O' and location[1][1] == 'O' and location[2][2] == 
    'O') or 
      (location[0][2] == 'O' and location[1][1] == 'O' and location[2][0] == 
    'O')):
      print (player2+" won the game!")
      turn = 10
    else:
      print("The game ended in a tie!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that the code checks after **every single turn** if the player whos turn it is won the game, if he did not win (yet) it prints your "else" meaning the `The game ended in a tie!`

Your solution would be to add another `if:` to you else-es that checks if all 9 fields are either filled with `X` or `O` and if that is the case you have to print your `The game ended in a tie!`